# Woocommerce: Is it possible to add a Product Category as a Attribute?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to add a Product Category as an Attribute? Want to do it with php, the reason I want to do this because I want to filter the categories with the Woocommerce widget, but it only filters Attribute.

[image: Woocommerce Widget]